# Scrolling animation of List<String> data in Text from up to down and once last index reached it should animate in reverse(down to up) with Icon change

Tags: flutter, dart

How to do scrolling animation of List data in Text from **up to down** and once last index reached it should animate in **reverse(down to up)**.
Animation will be like "Text In", "Text Halt" and "Text Out". Also while moving text it's **adjecent icon** should change and with "Text Halt", Icon should also halt.

Comment: Can you share an image or explain this sentence better ....Animation will be like "Text In", "Text Halt" and "Text Out"

Comment: @VipinKumarKashyap It will be something like https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aagarwal1012/Animated-Text-Kit/master/display/rotate.gif. Instead of text "Be", Icon will be there and that should also have change animation once text halt. But icon should not scroll. Icon should change only.

Comment: The gif you're using is from package animated_text_kit. You can just use the rotate example, and change the widget Text("BE) to an Icon widget